# How to work with OSX's system preferences without a mouse?

Tags: macos

My trackpad stopped working. I can't get a replacement now, so I've been working all day without it. Fortunately that was not a problem as I barely use it with VIM, ChromeVim, QuickSilver etc. Now I need to change some things on OSX System Preferences and I don't know how to. Is there a mouseless way to interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

Press Control-F1. It enables full keyboard access. This should allow you to easily navigate to the desired preference and change it.

I don't know which preference you want to modify, otherwise I could've provided more precise steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the command line your best option is the **defaults** command. For an example of what you can get look here:

https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/osx

That is a good starting point to do your own research. If there is something specific you want to change, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider AppleScript which is able to do UI scripting.

Edit : 
For example I used the following AppleScript recently to change my mouse settings (enabling/disabling natural scrolling on Mavericks) :

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell checkbox 1 of window 1
        click
    end tell
end tell
```